# Hide Now Playling Track Informations

Tags: spotify

is it possible, from an spotify application, to hide or overwrite the "now playing" pannel (the cover and artist name/track name of the playing track) ?

Thx, for your help.

I try to modify the Album object or the Track object provided to the player but it don't work :

```
models.Album.fromURI("spotify:album:3ty039P7JO7bTcWtWi1AP6", function(a) {  
var player = new v.Player();
var track = a.get(0);
//a.artist = "TOTO";
//a.cover = "sp://import/img/placeholders/300-album.png";       
//track.image = 'sp://import/img/placeholders/300-album.png';
track.name = "Test";
player.play(track,a);   
});
```

Comment: From *what* application? *What* "now playing" panel? In iTunes?

Comment: A kind of blindtest embeeded in spotify. I talk about the Now Playing in Spotify.

Comment: I try to modify the Album or Track object provided to player object but it don't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in the current API, mainly because we don't want people overwriting now playing information with adverts and stuff.